# Animating cells while UITableView is scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uitableview

I'm trying to achieve an effect wherein as a tableview is scrolling, the currently visible cells will animate according to where they are positioned on the screen. I'm somewhat new to IOS dev, so let me try to break it down:

- Tableview loads with custom cells User begins scrolling While the
- table is in motion, the visible cells have a UIView in which I would
  like to perform an animation that corresponds directly to the cell's
  current Y position on the screen.
- Cells will ONLY animate when they
  are visible
- Cell animation directly corresponds to table motion, i.e.
  whenever the table view scrolls, the cells are animating; once the
  table stops, the animations pause

One solution I have thought of is to update drawRect every single frame when the tableview is moving.  Depending on the graphic operations, this could be horrible performance wise.  Is there a way to grab the current table position every time it changes? Would I be better suited to use Core Animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your view controllers the delegate of the UITableView, and use all the methods of scrollview Delegate also. There you have many controls for start scrolling and end scrolling, and within thpse controls you could check for uitableview cell positioning.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks.  I figured there had to be a framework API to get this going, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful if you want to achieve something like below: 
**https://github.com/mrugrajsinh/AnimatedTableViewCellDemo**

[image]

Comment: nice work mrug but that not working expected function that jurk and some time finished animation not working with rectangle cell size

Answer (score 0):

You have to become delegate to this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

and this is the method to override and animate your cells:

```
– tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that won't be enough. It only informs you when the cell will become visible, it won't tell you where it's going to be displayed.

Comment: You're right. But what if you become delegate to this method of the scrollview protocol :scrollViewDidScroll: and then get indexPathsForVisibleRows from your TableView and animate those rows. Offcourse you would have to keep track of the cells you started to animate and the ones that you didn't. Anyway, maybe it is still a cleaner solution